# Why is TYPE_ORIENTATION deprecated since API 8.0 ?

Tags: android

Why is TYPE_ORIENTATION deprecated since API 8.0 for ANdroid? There's a cross in eclipse but the code runs perfectly fine.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/sO6rUfAlNeo

Answer (score 5):

In the Google I/O 2012 conference about sensors here: http://youtu.be/Q0V_ld7iNw4?t=23m23s at 23 minutes and 23 seconds it spoke about deprecating that function because on different devices such as tablets and smartphones, the default orientation is landscape in tablet, and portrait in handsets. If the coder is not aware of this, it will cause their device to run differently on these environments or when it gets rotated by 45 degrees. Its better to first get the device's default orientation by using  SensorManager.getOrientation() then perform your sensor computation accordingly.

Comment: Does that mean we cannot listen to sensor changes like this? `sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);`

Answer (score 0):

Depreciated code still works but it isn't guaranteed to work on future APIs. They are depreciated by code that works more effectively (and must operate that way as well), either with other code or as a whole. You should avoid depreciated code unless you really need to use it.

Comment: This is a good advice but doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because tablets are typically different than the default orientation used to be. (It was portrait, meaning the screen was taller than it was wide when held as normally expected. Tablets mean that the default is that the screen is wider than it is tall.)

This mean that a better mechanism needed to be found, which is [`android.view.Display.getOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29).

For more info, see [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html).

`Deprecated` means "This has been replaced by something better. It will still work for now, but you should look for the new replacement because it may stop working in the future", which explains why the code "runs perfectly fine" for you. It may work for years (or stop working in the next release), which is why you get the warning.